# Combinations algorithm k words n repeat in C#

Tags: c#

I need a combinations-algorithm which takes 2 informations from the user:

1. string list
2. repeat count(int)

I want to make combinations of user list repeat count. Like this;

```
Apple,Bear,Cat,Dog
3
```

Result:

```
Apple
Bear
Cat
Dog
Apple Bear
Bear Cat
Cat Dog
Apple Cat
Bear Dog
Apple Dog
Bear Cat Dog
Apple Bear Cat
Apple Bear Dog
Apple Cat Dog
```

I dont want:

```
Apple Apple or Apple Dog, Dog Apple etc.
```

How can i write this code? I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You'll need to show us what you've tried so far and where it's going wrong, this isn't a code writing service, unfortunately!

Comment: Your sample result is missing `Apple, Cat, Dog` I think.

Comment: yes matthew you are true, i forget to write apple cat dog result, i will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by observing that the presence or absence of any item in a combination can be represented by a single bit in a binary number. To represent the items, you would use one bit per item.

So you can produce all possible combinations of a set of N items by counting from 1 to 2^N-1. Then for each bit set in the number, you include the item at the corresponding index in the source array.

If you also have a limit on the maximum number of items in each combination, you can (before choosing the items for that number) check the number of 1 bits set in it, and skip that one if has too many bits set.

The number of bits set in a number is known as its [Hamming Weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight), and there are a number of fast ways to calculate this.

Putting all this together into a single compilable console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<string> sList = new List<string> { "Apple", "Bear", "Cat", "Dog" };

            var combinations = Combinations(sList, 3);

            foreach (var comb in combinations)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", comb));

            // If you must have the combinations in order of number of items, you would have to sort it by count.
            // This will be EXTREMELY SLOW for large sets of data!

            Console.WriteLine();
            combinations = Combinations(sList, 3).OrderBy(comb => comb.Count);

            foreach (var comb in combinations)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", comb));
        }

        /// <summary>Returns all the combinations of 'items' taken at most 'max' at a time.</summary>

        public static IEnumerable<List<T>> Combinations<T>(List<T> items, int max)
        {
            uint n = 1u << items.Count;

            for (uint i = 1; i < n; ++i)
            {
                int c = numBitsSet(i);

                if (c <= max)
                    yield return choose(items, c, i, n);
            }
        }

        static List<T> choose<T>(List<T> items, int count, uint mask, uint max)
        {
            var result = new List<T>(count);

            for (uint bit = 1, i = 0; bit < max; bit <<= 1, ++i)
                if ((mask & bit) != 0)
                    result.Add(items[(int)i]);

            return result;
        }

        static int numBitsSet(uint i)
        {
            i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
            i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
            return (int)(((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0Fu) * 0x01010101u) >> 24;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Regards, its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this project: [Permutations, Combinations, and Variations using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G) . It's worth reading and the classes are pretty efficient (at least much more than any LINQ approaches):

For example:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllCombinations<T>(IList<T> itemList, int countRepetition)
{
    for (int lowerIndex = 1; lowerIndex <= countRepetition; lowerIndex++)
    {
        var combinations = new Combinations<T>(itemList, lowerIndex, GenerateOption.WithoutRepetition);
        foreach (IList<T> combination in combinations)
            yield return combination;
    }
}
```

With your sample:

```
string[] items = {"Apple", "Bear", "Cat", "Dog"};
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> allCombinations = GetAllCombinations(items, 3);
foreach (IEnumerable<string> combination in allCombinations)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", combination));
```

Result:

```
Apple
Bear
Cat
Dog
Apple Bear
Apple Cat
Apple Dog
Bear Cat
Bear Dog
Cat Dog
Apple Bear Cat
Apple Bear Dog
Apple Cat Dog
Bear Cat Dog
```

Comment: `Combinations<T>` is undefined

Comment: @fubo: sure, that is not a class in the .NET framework. You need to download it from the link i've provided. It's part of the test-project which you can download at the top of the article. But the algorithm used is dicussed and explained in the article. The folder "Combinatorics" contains all classes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification.